# Postgresql: how to select from map of multiple values

Tags: sql, postgresql, multiple-value

I have a SOME_DELTA table which records all party related transactions with amount change
Ex.:

```
PARTY_ID   | SOME_DATE  | AMOUNT
--------------------------------
party_id_1 | 2019-01-01 | 100
party_id_1 | 2019-01-15 | 30
party_id_1 | 2019-01-15 | -60
party_id_1 | 2019-01-21 | 80
party_id_2 | 2019-01-02 | 50
party_id_2 | 2019-02-01 | 100
```

I have a case where where MVC controller accepts map someMap(party_id, some_date) and I need to get part_id list with summed amount till specific some_date

In this case if I send mapOf("party_id_1" to Date(2019 - 1 - 15), "party_id_2" to Date(2019 - 1 - 2))
I should get list of party_id with summed amount till some_date

Output should look like:

```
party_id_1 | 70
party_id_2 | 50
```

Currently code is:

```
select sum(amount) from SOME_DELTA where party_id=:partyId and some_date <= :someDate
```

But in this case I need to iterate through map and do multiple DB calls for summed amount for eatch party_id till some_date which feels wrong

Is there a more delicate way to get in one select query? (to avoid +100 DB calls)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a lateral join for this:

```
select map.party_id, 
       c.amount
from (
  values 
     ('party_id_1', date '2019-01-15'), 
     ('party_id_2', date '2019-01-02')
) map (party_id, cutoff_date)
  join lateral (
    select sum(amount) amount
    from some_delta sd
    where sd.party_id = map.party_id
      and sd.some_date <= map.cutoff_date
  ) c on true
order by map.party_id;
```

[Online example](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=ef5d705abdde3f0755601da9acaf0922)